# ServiceReference not updating at IIS 7

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7

At server I have web.config to my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2097152000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="524288000"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Server.FileServer.Service" behaviorConfiguration="Server.FileServer.Service1Behavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.217/FileServer/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <!-- Service Endpoints -->
      <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
      <endpoint address="" contract="Server.FileServer.IService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
        <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
      <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
      <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Server.FileServer.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="1000" />
       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I check it by wcf test client I have:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://SOMEADRESS.pl/FileServer/Server.FileServer.Service.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As you can see parameters of binding are not the same

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Thorarin is right, some information can't be propagated to client from server.
Checkout here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/dde72fbe-e741-48fd-a9e1-253800d5227a

Answer (score 2):

Binding parameters such as the buffer size do not automatically propagate from server to client when you create a service reference. You will have to adjust hem manually on the client side as well.

Was that the question? It's a little unclear to me what the problem is exactly.

Comment: The problem is that I put you web.config which is at server, but when I run Wcf Test Client (the tool from common7 in vs folder) I see different parameters. I'm not adding reference any client.

Comment: @phenevo: the title of your question is a little misleading then, but the same principle still holds. The binding parameters the server uses are not exposed to the client, so the client doesn't automatically use the same parameters.

Comment: I change the name of behaviorConfiguration, but I still see the previous name. I know that something is wrong , because when I use my winforms applicatio I get error when I try upload big(>10mb) file, but when I send small file everything is ok (1mb).